# Unterschied zwischen "sich definieren durch/über etw"

Tags: preposition

> Im 19 Jh. definierte sich die Frau **durch** den Status des Mannes.
>   Der im Juni 2003 vorgelegte Entwurf einer "Europäischen Strategie für Umwelt und Gesundheit" (SCALE) definiert sich **über** fünf Begriffe

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Präpositionen *durch* und *über* nach dem Verb "sich definieren"?

Comment: Interessante Beobachtung. Aber woher nimmst du die Überzeugung, dass im 19. Jahrhundert *x sich durch y definierte*? War diese Wendung überhaupt schon in Gebrauch? Oder kam sie erst in den 1960er Jahren auf - also im 20. Jahrhundert?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das ist eine Frage mit einer etwas verqueren Logik, etwa im Stil: "Wie konnte vor 65 Millionen Jahren ein Meteorit den Golf von Mexiko formen, wenn Isaac Newton erst im 17ten Jahrhundert das Gravitationsgesetz formulierte?". Dinge können auch passieren, ohne dass es eine Wendung dafür gibt.

Answer (score 1):

Die übliche und häufigere Wendung scheint mir mit "durch" gebildet zu werden, auch weil das Beispiel im Duden so gebildet ist.
Die Wendung mit "über" hat die gleiche Bedeutung und ist nicht missverständlich.

Answer (score 1):

Meine Vermutung:

"Durch" könnte im ersten Fall verwendet werden, da es eine "Eigenschaft (Status)" beschreibt.

Im zweiten Fall scheint es um eine Menge (5) zu gehen.